# MS Outlook 2010 - Force Automatic Replies to all Email Senders

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, out-of-office

I am setting up an out of office for a group mailbox that is acting as an intake point for a small triage team. The out of office message will be a canned response thanking the individual for reaching out and that their item/issue is being worked on. What we found in testing is that if the same person sends multiple emails to the group mailbox they do not get the out of office reply after the initial one is sent.

Is there a way to force an out of office reply every time the mailbox receives an email?

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/questions/125151/exchange-out-of-office-sending-an-ooo-reply-for-every-email you cant close as a duplicate from another SE site

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use a RULE rather than a simple OOO response. This allows far more control over what happens. However, you do need to be careful as some rules will only run client-side so need Outlook to be running.

[image]

This is Outlook 2013, starting with a blank rule gives you the most control. Not selecting a "condition" forces the rule to run on every incoming mail. You can then choose to reply.